# Smartwatch Samsung Galaxy and Android Studio - endless problems with Wi-Fi connects

Tags: android-studio, adb, sony-smartwatch, samsung, samsung-galaxy-watch-4

I'm author of "Connect Android Studio and Wear 3.0 smartwatch via wi-fi" on SO. After update of galaxy 4 smartwatch system software to 5.0 (OneUI) all recomendations are not working and command "connect :5555" leads to standard error (10061 - cannot connect to :5555).
All materials from samsung and google are read, steps from same Wi-Fi network, change port, change network and kill- start -server to restart and rebuild everything are done.
Sometimes the smartwatch is answering on the ping  successfully, but it's not leading to connect to Android Studio. I re-install everything (ADB, Android Studio, smartwatch system software) and don't have any new guess how to overcame this stop-factor in development. Please help.